# laravel 8, Class "App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Category" not found {"exception":{}}

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am studying Laravel 8, using this code, but error :(
please tell me how to fix

> Class "App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Category" not found {"exception":{}}

**code in Category Controller.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
        public function index()
    {
      $categories = Category::paginate(2);
        return view('admin.categories.index', compact('categories'));
    }
```

**code in web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'MainController@index')->name('admin.index');
        Route::resource('/categories', 'CategoryController');
});
```

**Screenshots:**

[Class "App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Category" not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYeEr.jpg)

[web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCuHp.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `Category` is a model. So simply at the following at line 4:

```
use App\Models\Category;
```

Comment: added and got another error [link](http://prntscr.com/179h6xb)

Comment: @Alex67 Do you not have a `Category.php` ? If the file is located at `app/Category.php`, it should be `use App\Category;` instead.

Comment: not have category.php in app  [link](http://prntscr.com/17bfkbs)

Comment: @Alex67 You have a typo in the name of your file. You've named it `Categoty.php` instead of `Category.php` under `app/Models`.

Comment: NetBins showed me these files in red. Yes, that's the problem. Many thanks for your help, Chin